# How to use Winston3 to log events in the Windows Event Log?

Tags: node.js, event-log, winston

I would like to log messages from a nodejs service into the Windows Event Log.

I found [winston-winlog](https://github.com/jfromaniello/winston-winlog) and [winston-winlog2](https://github.com/peteward44/winston-winlog2) modules, but they all use old winston version.

How to make a custom Transport for Winston3 to log in the Windows Event Log ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I made thanks to [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows) module :

```js
    const Transport      = require('winston-transport');
    const WinEventLogger = require('node-windows').EventLogger;

    class WinstonWinlogTransport extends Transport {
        constructor(opts) {
            super(opts);
            this.logger = new WinEventLogger(opts);
        }

        log(info, callback) {
            setImmediate(() => {
                this.emit('logged', info);
            });
            let {message, level} = info ;
            if ( level==='error' ) this.logger.error(message) ;
            else if ( level==='warn' ) this.logger.warn(message) ;
            else this.logger.info(message) ;
            callback();
        }
    };
```

Then you can create transports and add them to your winston logger :

```js
    let myTransport = new WinstonWinlogTransport({ source: 'Label1' }) ;  // Go to "Applications" logs
    let myOtherTransport = new WinstonWinlogTransport({ source: 'Label2', eventLog: 'SYSTEM' }) ;  // Go to "System" logs
```

Note that your nodejs service have to be installed with administrator privilleges. (To install nodejs code as a windows service, I used [WinSW](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw/blob/master/doc/installation.md))